# Deselect empty specific horizontal axes labels from Excel Chart though vba code

Tags: excel, vba

I have an Excel bar chart, with horizontal axis labels. Some of the title labels are blank as shown in the graph. How I can I deselect these labels form the the axis labels so they are not shown in the graph through vba code.

Thank you and your help is much appreciated... 
[image]

Comment: Have you tried recording a macro? if so what did it show?

Comment: Yes I did , no codes were showed regarding the deselect..

Answer (score 0):

I just avoided the whole deselecting thing by building the Chart CollectionSeries XValues and Values string based on the required specific cells. Avoiding the blank empty cell.

```
Dim chartPhaseXValues As String
Dim chartDurationValues As String
'For Loop Here
chartPhaseXValues = chartPhaseXValues & oExcel.ActiveSheet.Name & "!" & _
                    oExcel.Range("A1").Offset(rowCount, 1).Address & ","
hartDurationValues = chartDurationValues & oExcel.ActiveSheet.Name & "!" & _
                     oExcel.Range("A1").Offset(rowCount, 4).Address & ","
'End For Loop

' Remove the trailing , at the end of each string
chartPhaseXValues = Left(chartPhaseXValues, Len(chartPhaseXValues) - 1)
chartDurationValues = Left(chartDurationValues, Len(chartDurationValues) - 1)

' Add the Series to the graph
oExcel.ActiveChart.SeriesCollection.NewSeries
oExcel.ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(1).Name = "=""StartDate"""
oExcel.ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(1).Values = "=" & chartDurationValues
oExcel.ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(1).XValues = "=" & chartPhaseXValues
```